Why is LaTeX counting solution as is a theorem?
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm,right=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec, fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\LARGE\scshape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktoc=all,     
    linkcolor=blue
}
\title{A Study of Finite Transformation Semigroup}
\newenvironment{sistema}
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}
    {\end{array}\right.}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[oem]{}{3.3em}{1pc}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\mbox{}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
      some exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
   sol of the exercise
\end{solution}
\end{document}

The output to this is:

Exercise 0.0.1. some exercise


Solution 1. sol of the exercise


Please explain what the end goal is. It is not clear from the question as it is now.

Do you notice a difference between \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise} and \newtheorem{solution}{Solution}? Did you maybe mean to specify \newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}?

Aside: I hate to have to be the bearer of bad news, but maybe you're already fully aware of the following issue anyway: Your document's preamble is a horrible mess.  For instance, there can be no satisfactory reason for loading five [5!] text font packages -- txfonts, lmodern, times, newtxtext, and pxfonts. FWIW, I cannot manage to compile your test document correctlly under either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Do yourself a big favor and start cleaning up, simplifying, and streamlining your document's preamble.

You're doing
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

after
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

This means that if you have a theorem as the first thing in chapter 1, section 1, it will be numbered 1.1.1. If an exercise follows, it will be numbered 1.1.2 as you requested.
Since you later do
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

you get that the first solution will be numbered 1, the second one 2 and so on, independently on chapters and sections.
If you don't want solutions to be numbered, ensure you load amsthm and do
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

If you don't want that exercises share their numbering with theorems, do
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

or maybe [chapter] instead of [section], so as to consecutively number exercises throughout a chapter.

Now some comments about your preamble:

a4wide has been deprecated for about 30 years and, since you later use geometry it makes no sense.

mdwlist has been unmaintained for about 30 years; instead of using it together with enumerate, load enumitem instead (assuming you want to customize lists, I mean).

Three packages aimed at commutative diagrams is too many. There's little reason nowadays to load amscd and tikz-cd, which you load through \usetikzlibrary{cd}, is much better than xy.

You're loading graphicx multiple times. The package epsfig is for compatibility with decades old documents; epstopdf is not needed.

txfonts lmodern times newtxtext pxfonts are font packages that are mostly incompatible with fontspec. Also fontenc with T1 is incompatible with fontspec.

subfigure has been deprecated for two decades.


Don't take your old preamble, maybe passed on by some “friend” and add whatever you think fit for a new document. With this approach you get

old and deprecated packages;
contradictions;
incompatibilities.

When you begin work on a new document, start afresh, loading only the packages you need for it.
